# How can I destroy generated (cloned) obstacles in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

The obstacles are generated using a generate script, and the main game object is in the prefabs folder. I have attached the game object with the generate script, the problem is that it is not destroyed. I have tried using the `OnBecameInvisbile()` method in the `Generate` script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Generate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject rocks;

    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("CreateObstacle", 3f, 3f);
    }

    void CreateObstacle()
    {
        Instantiate(rocks);
    }

    void OnBecameInvisible() 
    {
        Destroy(this.rocks);
    } 
}
```

---

How do I destroy the generated obstacles?

Comment: Can you clarify, do you want... A) When your `Generate` object becomes invisible, all `rocks` are destroyed (here you may also want to pause creating obstacles), or B) When each `rocks` instance becomes invisible, that single `rocks` object is destroyed, leaving the rest intact ? If you want this to react to visibility events on each rock, then you'll need a separate script on the rocks.

Comment: Based off your previous comments on the deleted answer, I have to ask *what you actually mean* by `OnBecameInvisible`; or rather, when do you think this is calling? You commented on the original version to say it did not work; I tested it, myself, and it did.

Comment: As I have already pointed out, you report your code not working. I test that it, in fact, does. The same goes for smk's answer. It seems that your issue is in not using 'OnBecameInvisible' correctly, but you *need* to give us more information to be able to help.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late replays it was working before but i dont know what happend now its get cloned and still in the hierarchy and Onbecomeinvisbile means when its out of main camera

Comment: I have to deleter the rocks objects when it out of camera

Comment: Im new to unity can u explain what does this OnbecameInvisible means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding this script to your prefab bullet:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Bullet: MonoBehaviour
{

    void OnBecameInvisible()
    {
        // Destroy the when Become Invisible 
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```